# How to exclude properties of father class

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

Suppose I have the following two classes.

```
  public class Father
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; } 
    }
    public class Child: Father
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I know if a specific property is a Father property (Inherited) or a Child property?

I tried

```
var childProperties = typeof(Child).GetProperties().Except(typeof(Father).GetProperties());
```

but seems like Except is not detecting the equality of Father properties and Child inherited properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just try like this;

```
var childPropertiesOnly = typeof(Child)
         .GetProperties()
         .Where(x => x.DeclaringType != typeof(Father))
         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the overload on [`GetProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts [`BindingFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx). Include the `DeclaredOnly` flag next to the `Public` and `Instance` flags and you're all set:

```
var childProperties = typeof(Child)
            .GetProperties(
                BindingFlags.Public | 
                BindingFlags.Instance | 
                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly  // to search only the properties declared on 
                                           // the Type, not properties that 
                                           // were simply inherited.
            );
```

This will return one property, the Name.

[image: exclude inherited properties debug]

Notice that with this solution you don't need to inspect the DeclaringType.

Answer (score 5):

Inspect the [`DeclaringType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Reflection_MemberInfo_DeclaringType) property on the `PropertyInfo`. That should tell you enough information.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the properties defined by a class but not the inherited ones, you can pass the binding flag `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` to the `GetProperties` method.

Ref: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx

**Edit 1:**
Thanks rene for pointing out that this is not yet a working answer.
Actually, I do often forget to pass those mandatory binding flags to `GetXXX` methods.
And the program always crashes as expected...

Anyway, in order to make the method work, one should always specify 1) the visibility/accessibility (that is, public or not) and 2) the scope (static/instance) of the desired members.
If you don't, the return value of `GetXXX` will be null (or an empty array, I am not quite sure about that, but you get the idea.)

In conclusion, to get things correct, you sould:
1. Choose from `BindingFlags.Public` or `BindingFlags.NonPublic` or both.
2. Choose from `BindingFlags.Instance` or `BidningFlags.Static` or both.
3. Combine the chosen flags from the former steps with `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`

So in your case the result will be the line listed in rene's answer.
(I have to edit the answer because it seems that I cannot comment yet...)